# What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial d_A} f$ where $d_A$ is matrix $A$'s diagonal?

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let us assume that we know $\frac{\partial}{\partial A} f$, where $f$ is a scalar function, and $A$ any matrix.

Now suppose we are interested in the special case when $A$ is diagonal, and we want to know what's $$\frac{\partial}{\partial d_A} f$$ where $d_A$ is matrix $A$'s diagonal.

Also, what would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial d_A} A$?

Comment: It's totally unclear what you have in mind. Give a more detailed description of the envisaged mathematical situation.

Comment: you cannot define the differential for just diagonal matrices, if not for the variable of $f$. In any case a matrix is isomorphic to a vector space so you can apply the multivariable derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have calculated the gradient of the function $f(A)$
$$G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$$
with no constraints on the matrix variable, and now you wish to constrain $A$ to be diagonal, i.e. 
$$A={\rm Diag}(a)$$
Start with a differential in terms of $dA$, then change the variable to $da$
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dA \cr
   &= G:{\rm Diag}(da) \cr
   &= {\rm diag}(G):da \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
 &= {\rm diag}(G) \cr
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}\Big) \cr
}$$
where

$\,\,\,:\,\,$ is a product notation for the trace $\,\,A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

$\,\,\,{\rm Diag}()$ generates a diagonal matrix from the input vector

${\,\,\,\rm diag}()$ extracts the diagonal of a matrix into an output vector

Comment: Lynn, thanks for the answer. The result it's what I expected it to be, but I'm not sure the equality $G:Diag(da)=diag(G):da$? is  Diag ->diagonal matrix generated from a vector and diag ->main diagonal of matrix ? ?

Comment: Decompose the gradient into a sum of its diagonal and off-diagonal parts. Only the diagonal part will contribute to the above trace product; the product with the off-diagonal part is zero.

Comment: Lynn, many thanks ;)

Comment: lynn, if we had $A=Diag(e^a_i)$, then what would $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} f$ be ?  where $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$. I get $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} f = diag(\frac{\partial}{\partial A} f ^\intercal A)$

Comment: Assuming you mean
$$\eqalign{
 x & = \exp(a) &\implies dx = x\odot da\cr
 A &= {\rm Diag}(x) \cr
}$$
Then the calculation runs as follows
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= G:dA \cr
 &= {\rm diag}(G):dx \cr
 &= {\rm diag}(G):x\odot da \cr
 &= x\odot {\rm diag}(G):da \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= x\odot {\rm diag}(G) \cr
}$$ where the exp function is applied element-wise and $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product.

Comment: Lynn, in my comment above I meant $A=Diag(e^{a_i})$. I'm not exactly sure I understand what $\exp(a)$ is in your comment... Could you, in your answer, elaborate a bit on this? I'll give you a +1;)